# Island Sizes problem giving maximum recursion depth error

Tags: python, recursion, gaps-and-islands

I am solving the problem of finding the sizes of all islands existing in an nxm matrix. I used a recursive method and have no clue what the bug in my code is that is causing the maximum recursion depth error. Thank you in advance :)

```
def riverSizes(matrix):
    returnList = []
    for row in range(len(matrix)):
        for column in range(len(matrix[row])):
            if matrix[row][column] == 1:
                returnList.append(visitConnected(matrix,row,column))
                
def visitConnected(matrix,row,column,size=0):
    if inBounds(row,column,matrix):
        if matrix[row][column] == 1:
            matrix[row][column] == -1
            size += 1
            size += visitConnected(matrix,row +1,column)
            size += visitConnected(matrix,row - 1,column)
            size += visitConnected(matrix,row,column+1)
            size += visitConnected(matrix,row,column-1)
        else:
            return size
    else:
        return size

        
def inBounds(row,column,matrix):
    return row >= 0 and row < len(matrix) and column >= 0 and column < len(matrix[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing examples or invocation I can see at least one issue.  Consider the matrix `[[1, 1]]`.
`visitConnected(..., 0, 0)` will call `size += visitConnected(..., 0, 1)`, which will call `size += visitConnected(..., 0, 0)`, so you will never terminate.

You write `matrix[row][column] == -1` instead of `matrix[row][column] = -1`, so nothing happens there.  You also don't return the final size, so your returnlist will be all `None`.

Comment: I have the line in my code that says matrix[row][column] = -1 so the code knows it is has already been visited and in turn does not recurse through it again, did I implement that line wrong?

Comment: No, that line doesn't set anything, which is the root cause.  Your function doesn't return the size it calculates, which will be a different issue.

Comment: I made sure it returns the size of each of the recursvie steps it takes, does the 1 not change to -1 when i go down a depth level?

Comment: Check my answer, you have a typo.